# Diffence between the double slit experiment, single slit diffraction vs the hair strand diffraction experiment

Tags: optics, interference, double-slit-experiment, diffraction

We know that in the double slit experiment the BRIGHT spots are created for path difference of $n\lambda$.However the condition is reversed in the case of diffraction. Here we see BRIGHT spots when the path difference is $(2n+1)\frac{\lambda}{2}$. The other difference is that ideally the fringe widths and intensity in the double slit experiment should be same but they should diminish quickly in case of diffraction as we move away from the centre.
I have conducted the the hair strand experiment in my home with a laser which can be a considered a single obstacle diffraction. Because I have seen that just like in slit diffraction, the central bright spot is the brightest and the widest. However the fringe widths of the adjacent fringes DON'T decrease as quickly or significantly as I thought they were rather spaced and except the central maximum the first 4 fringe widths were almost same (around $2.2\space cm$).However after the first 8 or 9 fringes the widths start changing and the pattern starts vanishing. What might be the reason for this nature of diffraction for the hair strand experiment

Comment: This is a good question but very difficult to answer because it lacks essential information. The experimental set up of the hair strand experiment and in particular the distance between the laser and the hair, and the hair and the screen. A sketch (with dimensions) of the diffraction pattern observed on the screen.  You write "the widths start changing" but do not give details of the changes.

Comment: Should I maybe add pictures of the pattern and make some measurements??